# Function not being recognized as being called in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have a function on my "Functions.php" page:

```
function displaySearchedGame($game) {
    if (empty($game)) {
        echo '<p>No games found.</p>';
        return;
    }
    echo '<ul class="searchedGamesList">';
    foreach ($game as $game) {
        echo '<li class="searchedGame">';
        
        // Display the cover image if URL is defined
        if ($game['cover_url']) {
            echo '<img src="' . $game['cover_url'] . '" alt="Game Cover">';
        }

        echo '<div class="game-details">';
        echo '<h3>' . $game['game_name'] . '</h3>';
        echo '<p>Platform: ' . ($game['platform_name'] ?? 'Unknown Platform') . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

and I'm trying to call it in the click function in my javascript on dashboard.php:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var searchTerm =document.getElementById('search').value;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'Functions.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onreadystatechange =function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    displaySearchedGame(response);
                }
            };
            xhr.send('action=searchGame&searchTerm=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm));
        });
    });
```

my Functions.php is not recognizing that I'm calling displaySearchedGame() within the javascript, and I keep getting the error "displaySearchedGame" not defined.

I've tried a number of different ways to call the function. I even tried calling it from my php on dashboard.php but it only returned "null". What I want it to do is to take the searched for game using my searchGame():

```
function searchGame($searchTerm) {
    // Prepare the URL for the AJAX request
    $url = "search_game.php?searchTerm=" . urlencode($searchTerm);

    // Initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    // Execute the cURL request and get the response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors and close the cURL session
    if ($response === false) {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return "Error: " . $error;
    }

    // Close the cURL session
    curl_close($ch);

    // Return the response
    return $response;
}
```

and returned the games searched for. I want the functions to be on the functions.php so I can use/call them from another page as well.

Comment: You cannot directly call a function in PHP via JavaScript. You can use xhr to call a PHP file that will launch a PHP function and return the result (if necessary) in response to the call.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing? I'm calling the xhr, or are you saying there's no way for me to save the functions to use globally like that?

Comment: JS works in the client's browser, and PHP works on the server. They can't exchange functions and don't know who does what and how. JS can call a PHP file on the server and pass parameters to it, and the PHP file must execute the necessary code and return the result. Now you are trying to call a PHP function in the client's browser. It won't work that way.

Comment: `Isn't that what I'm already doing` ....no. you're calling `displaySearchedGame` as if it was a JS function. It's not, it's a php function. Therefore it needs to be invoked by php code. JS and php know absolutely nothing about each other. They run in different environments, at different times in the lifecycle of a web application and usually (except perhaps for a local development setup) on completely different computers. They communicate only by sending and receiving HTTP requests.

Comment: You can "use the functions globally" because there is no such context. It's like speaking in Spanish and expecting it to be understood by a Mandarin speaker (who doesn't speak Spanish and also can't hear you).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like this

On server side Functions.php

```
// Get POST parameter
$req = $_POST['searchTerm'];

function searchGame($searchTerm) {
    // some code to search
}

function displaySearchedGame($game) {
    // your code to prepare render
}

// call functions
displaySearchedGame(searchGame($req));
```

on client side

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    document.getElementById('someContainerToRender').InnerHTML = response;
}
```